# Making this code for image resize() work

Tags: java, image, netbeans6.5

My instructor sent me this code, which is supposed to be an integral part of an ongoing project. Thing is, it doesn't work.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.Kernel;
import java.awt.image.ConvolveOp;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGEncodeParam;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ImageUtil {

    public static void resize(File originalFile, File resizedFile, int newWidth, float quality) throws IOException{

        if(quality <0||quality>1){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("quality has to be between 0 and 1");

        }

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(originalFile.getCanonicalPath());
        Image i = ii.getImage();
        Image resizedImage = null;

        int iWidth = i.getWidth (null);
        int iHeight = i.getHeight(null);

        if (iWidth > iHeight){
            resizedImage = i.getScaledInstance(newWidth,(newWidth*iHeight)/iWidth, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        } else {
            resizedImage = i.getScaledInstance((newWidth*iWidth)/iHeight,newWidth, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        }

        Image temp = new ImageIcon (resizedImage).getImage();

        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage (temp.getWidth(null), temp.getHeight(null),
                                                         BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        // copy to a buffered image
        Graphics g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0,0,temp.getWidth(null), temp.getHeight(null)); // causea el error de ejecución?
        g.drawImage(temp,0,0,null);
        g.dispose();

        float softenFactor = 0.05f;
        float [] softenArray = {0, softenFactor,0, softenFactor, 1-(softenFactor*4), softenFactor,0, softenFactor,0};
        Kernel kernel = new Kernel (3,3,softenArray);
        ConvolveOp cOp = new ConvolveOp (kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,null);
        bufferedImage = cOp.filter (bufferedImage,null);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(resizedFile);

        JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);

        JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(bufferedImage);

        param.setQuality(quality,true);

        encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(param);
        encoder.encode(bufferedImage);



    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
       File originalImage= new File ("/images/goya.jpg");
       resize(originalImage,new File("/images/goyanuevotamanio.jpg"),350, 0.2f);
       resize(originalImage, new File("/images/goyanuevotamanio.jpg"), 350, 1f);

    }

}
```

He says the code should be able to resize both height and width yet his resize method:

```
public static void resize(File originalFile, File resizedFile, int newWidth, float quality)
```

lacks a `newHeight` parameter.

The RuntimeException that's thrown says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Width (-1) and height (-1) cannot be <= 0**
        at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:999)
        at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:312)
        at ImageUtil.resize(ImageUtil.java:38)
        at ImageUtil.main(ImageUtil.java:72)
Java Result: 1
```

How can I change this?

Comment: What parameters are being used when resize is called?

Comment: resize(originalImage,new File("/images/goyanuevotamanio.jpg"),350, 0.2f);

Comment: oops, I should have seen that further down :) 
If you are sure there are no problems with /images/goya.jpg then I'll have to actually run this to be of further help. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: yeah, the file is ok. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without analyzing the code to see what the problem might be, I can say that if the intention is to keep the images aspect ratio, a new height parameter is not needed. It will always be a fixed ratio of the width.

**UPDATE:**

I've run the code against my own test image and it does indeed work as expected. The error you are getting is most likely caused when the program cannot find the source image you specify. I get the same error when I specify a source image that doesn't exist.

Try using an absolute path (including drive letter etc.) for your source image.

**UPDATE 2**

Add the following code after the line..

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(originalFile.getCanonicalPath());

if(ii.getImageLoadStatus() == MediaTracker.COMPLETE)
{
    System.out.print("Load image ok\n");
}
else
{
    System.out.print("Load image failed\n");
}
```

This will tell you if the program is failing to load the source image.

Comment: Why is the exception complaining about the height value passed then?

Comment: That's what we need to find out. An image has a height, but a resize function doesn't need to specify a height parameter if the aspect ratio is to be maintained and a new width is provided.

Comment: The height parameter mentioned in the exception, I think, is temp.getHeight(null) which is being passed to new BufferedImage.

Comment: I ran it on windows using resize(originalImage,new File("C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/Galeria/src/imagesgoyanuevotamanio.jpg"),350, 0.2f);

and the code gave the same Exception, what I'm I missing?

Comment: The long path there is the output file. The problem is with the input file..
  File originalImage= new File ("/images/goya.jpg");
This is the one you need to specify a full path for or correct the relative path. I'll add an edit above with some code to verify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why you apply soften to resize it have to be sharpen Kernal -1 -2 -1 -2 12+q -2 -1 -2 -1 where a tipical q could be 28 and you are not applyng the resize version of drawImage

(q = 36 is equivalent to your F=0.05 for sharpen)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the stack trace the exception is thrown by this line:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage (temp.getWidth(null), temp.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

I would think this is probably because `temp.getWidth` and `temp.getHeight` are returning -1 because the image has not finished loading.

There are tutorials and examples for working with images in Java available on the web. One sample is here http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/92. Look for the code using `ImageObserver`.

Comment: Obsolete link: "The requested resource...is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address"

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the program a starting parameter between 0 and 1.
I did it and it work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

adapt this:

```
private void ResizeImage(Image img, double maxWidth, double maxHeight)
{
    double srcWidth = img.Source.Width;
    double srcHeight = img.Source.Height;

    double resizeWidth = srcWidth;
    double resizeHeight = srcHeight;

    double aspect = resizeWidth / resizeHeight;

    if (resizeWidth > maxWidth)
    {
        resizeWidth = maxWidth;
        resizeHeight = resizeWidth / aspect;
    }
    if (resizeHeight > maxHeight)
    {
        aspect = resizeWidth / resizeHeight;
        resizeHeight = maxHeight;
        resizeWidth = resizeHeight * aspect;
    }

    img.Width = resizeWidth;
    img.Height = resizeHeight;
}
```